# Issue connecting to mysql database using hibernate.xml

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am unable to connect to a mysql database using xml. I have no problem using an hibernate.properties file, but when i substitute it with an xml it doesn't work. The xml in `main/resources` is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances</property>
    <property name="connection.username">infinite</property>
    <property name="connection.password">skills</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <mapping class="com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have a utility SessionFactory class that returns this

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        return configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in building the factory");
    }
}
```

After i retrieve it and i call the method `.openSession()` i have the following error

```
WARN - HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
WARN - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
... 15 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in building the factory
at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:22)
at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
... 1 more
```

Comment: Try `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>`. Note that 'hibernate.' prefix.

Comment: It gives me the same error even if i change it to `hibernate.dialect`

Answer (score 0):

Add in your library path **MySQL Connector JDBC driver** for MySQL (JAR)

Link [ https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j ]

Answer (score 0):

You are not .configuring() the `Configuration` object with the hibernate.cfg.xml
so it's not picking up those properties.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");  //Resource path or File
```

Comment: I fixed the xml and added the `.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml)` . But now i'm having **Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User** when i call `session.save()`

Comment: hibernate-core 5.2.12.Final

Comment: I can fix it by adding `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);` but that removes any benefit of using an xml instead of a .properties file.

Comment: Well it works perfectly if i use `hibernate-core 4.3.6.Final` , need to work around classes since i cannot use try with resources but other than that it reads the `hibernate.cfg.xml` . I would prefer to use the most recent version though, is the configuration supposed to be done in a different way ?

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernate config file is using wrong parameter names. Correct param names are as below:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class
hibernate.connection.url
hibernate.connection.username
hibernate.connection.password
hibernate.dialect
hibernate.show_sql
```

Correct your param names and try again.

Refer this link for detailed list of param names: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: I have the same errors even if i add `hibernate` to the property name