# Issues configuring hibernate with hibernate-core 5.0

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Update to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47759117/issue-connecting-to-mysql-database-using-hibernate-xml/47768723?noredirect=1#comment82499439_47768723).
I am unable to configure persistency with both hibernate (`Configuration.buildSessionFactory`) or base jpa (`Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory`) if i use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In the hibernate case i have `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances</property>
    <property name="connection.username">infinite</property>
    <property name="connection.password">skills</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>


    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User"/>
    <mapping class="com.infiniteskills.data.entities.Bank"/>

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

placed under `src/main/resources`. Classes are mapped this way

```
<mapping class="com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User"/>
<mapping class="com.infiniteskills.data.entities.Bank"/>
```

If i run

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
return configuration
    .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build()).openSession();
```

Whenever i try to use session methods that call configured classes it gives me **org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: [class-name]**

It works perfectly if i use version `4.3.6.Final`.

---

If instead i have a jpa configuration using a `persistence.xml` under `src/main/resources/META-INF`

```
 <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="infinite-finances">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="infinite"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="skills"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and i configure it using

```
EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("infinite-finances").createEntityManager();
```

I have **Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named infinite-finances** with `5.2.12.Final` , and here again it configures and works perfectly with `4.3.6.Final` instead.

Comment: How does your persistence.xml look like?

Comment: edited in the post.

Comment: so have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410183/hibernate-5-2-2-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager

Comment: Yes, that fixed it for the `persistence.xml` but what am i supposed to do for the `hibernate.cfg.xml` ? I've added it in the post

Comment: is hibrenate.cfg.xml in the root of the classpath?

Comment: Since it's a maven project it's under src/main/resources, if i place it anywhere else i have `Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]`